# Python and pylint in VSCode

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, package, pylint

On my VSCode editor I run a venv on conda.
Python version is 3.8 in the venv.
Importing package OpenCV as
`import cv2`
spits out pylint error like
`Module 'cv2' has no 'xyz' member`
But importing the package using    `from cv2 import cv2` runs perfectly well. Why is that and what is the way to correct that permanently on vscode on my ubuntu machine?

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided, I installed the module "`opencv`" on my computer, and VSCode did not display the pylint error when using it:

[image]

The way I installed the module "`opencv`":  `pip install opencv-python`

My `settings.json`:

> ```
> {
>   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
>     "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
>     "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
>     "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
>     "python.linting.enabled": true, 
>     "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
>     "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
> }
> ```

Reference: [Opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).